# Сокращение длинных слов в тексте

Tags: php

```
$text="123 123456 12 123";
```

Как можно пробежаться по этому тексту и длинные слова сократить на 5 символов максимум, т.е. 123456 - должно сократиться в 12345 и получиться на выходе:

```
$text2="123 12345 12 123";
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$str = '123 12345678 12345 123456';
echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/\w{6,}/',
    function($m){ return substr($m[0], 0, 5); },
    $str
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну можно и попроще:

```
  $text="123 123456 12 123";
  $words = explode(' ',$text);
  for($i=0;$i<count($words);$i++)
  $words[$i] = mb_substr(trim($words[$i]),0,5,"UTF-8");
  $text = implode(' ',$words);

  echo $text;  //  "123 12345 12 123"
```

**Как видно, вывод именно тот, которые требуется.**

Comment: А если между некоторыми словами будет по 2 пробела, или табуляция? Или, что вероятнее, после слова без пробела будет идти знак препинания? Например: `$text="123, (123456) 12 123.";`

Comment: Ну все это легко поправить. Спасибо.

Просто до этого, на мой взгляд, автор сам должен дойти.

Comment: >Ну все это легко поправить.
Разумеется. Только фраза "Ну можно и попроще" вызывает сомнения.

Comment: Ага, наверное =)